# Safecracker Registration & EE's registration process, Forgot Password

Tags: members, registration, safecracker-registration, member-details, forgot-password

I'm using Safecracker Registration. There are a few things I want to improve for my registration process. I'm not sure if this is something I need to do in Safecracker Registration or in EE.

**Registration Process Questions**

Upon submitting the registration form, users are NOT loggged in and are directed to a page that tells them to verify their email address. Everything is good so far.

1. When the user checks their email and clicks the activation link, I want the user to be directed to a page that I specify instead of EE's default page.
2. When the user gets to the activation page (whether it's mine or EE's), I want the user automatically logged in. The assumption is that only the user has access to his/her email and clicking the activation link essentially confirmed the identity of the user -- thus, this is safe.

**Forgot Password**

1. This process sends an initial email to the user, which then sends another email with the new password if the user clicks the link in the initial email. How do I get these links to direct to my template pages instead of EE's?

**Synchronizing Information**

1. My member's Channel (the one associated via SafeCracker Registration) has a `{profile_name}` field. Whenever this is set, I'd like to sync it up with EE's `{screen_name}`. How do I do this?

Comment: To use custom pages instead of EE default pages, check out the Custom System Messages add-on. http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages

Comment: I would recommend looking at Zoo Visitor http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-visitor which I believe will do most of what you want.

Comment: For future reference, it's best if you submit one question per question - otherwise it makes it hard for people to vote up answers which only answer one of your questions (and it's unlikely someone will be able to answer all of your questions in one go).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Synchronizing Information**
>
> My member's Channel (the one associated via SafeCracker Registration)
>   has a {profile_name} field. Whenever this is set, I'd like to sync it
>   up with EE's {screen_name}. How do I do this?

I took a glace at "SafeCracker Registration" module settings but there isn't any such type of settings. You can develop a small extension with hook entry_submission_end. The author_id of that member entry will be the member id of newly created member. So it would be easy to update the member's screen_name with entry's profile_name field value.

Answer (score 0):

For your registration process questions, the add-on [Member Activation Redirect](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/member-activation-redirect) fulfils both requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether Safecracker Registration handles templating the forgot password process, but if not there are other add-ons which can do this. For example, [Freemember](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember) lets you template your own reset password page once the user clicks a link in their email.